# StartX fails, insufficient memory?

Tags: display, memory

Some days back, I added a network printer at my institute. While trying to print for the first time, the computer asked for authentication, then complained of low disk space. I deleted a 3 GB movie from the Desktop and restarted the computer.

Now Gnome does not start.

I first got a screen which said something like "Starting cups server.." at the end.
I went back and deleted all the files that had been created recently in /etc/cups/.
Now the screen says that it is starting GDM, then stopping GDM and the last message is something like "Stopping Jupiter dameon..".

I could drop to the command line and login....a "df -h" showed that the usage in "/" is 100%. I deleted some 3 GB of files from /home. Now "df -h" shows 3 GB difference between total space and available space but the usage is still listed as 100%

I tried "startx"....I get a blank screen ...dropping to command line, I see the following messages...

fglrx: No matching device section for instance (BUSID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
Waiting for X server to begin accepting connections...
No protocol specified...
No protocol specified...

If I login as root, am able to start X, but the screen just shows a completely empty desktop.....am unable to do anything....

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check system logs in /var/log/syslog ?
2. it is possible that the file system has been corrupted for some reason...
   In this case **I would backup any data** and try to force a disk check at next reboot:

   $ sudo touch /forcefsck

Comment: tried that...it said "bad format on line 21 of /etc/fstab"

Comment: OK, give us the content of your /etc/fstab